# How to make hover use border-radius first-child

Tags: html, css

I am working on a small website and I have a menu with the border-radius set to 10px. I am having problem on how to make the hover use the border-radius only on the first and last child. 
Can somebody explain me what am I doing wrong?

```
<div class="menu">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Link 1 </a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 2 </a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 3 </a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 4 </a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 5 </a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.menu ul
{
    background: #ede0b3;
    width: 200px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px grey;
    border-radius: 10px; 
    margin-left: 5px;
} 

.menu ul li
{
    list-style: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
}

.menu ul li a
{
    padding: 10px 15px;
    display: block;
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none; 
}

.menu ul li:last-child
{
    border-bottom: none;

}

.menu ul li a:hover
{
    background: white; 
}

.menu li a:first-child:hover
{
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/vaydrvcr/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, is the updated fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/vaydrvcr/1/

You were correct, just you missed that `a` is always the first child of `li`. You were to target anchor of first li.

Comment: Thanks bro, exactly what i was looking for

Comment: The UI is not yet clean, if you hover over the last item, the white corner is popping out of the main ul.

Comment: @ShashankAgrawal I guess, this is very much a test case. So, we can forgo the UI :p

Comment: Oh okay! Well, even for test cases, UI matters to me a lot always :-)

Answer (score 2):

Use This method

```css
.menu ul
{
 background: #ccc;
 width: 200px;
 box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px grey;
 border-radius: 10px; 
 margin-left: 5px;
} 

.menu ul li
{
 list-style: none;
 border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
}

.menu ul li a
{
 padding: 10px 15px;
 display: block;
 color: black;
 font-weight: bold;
 text-decoration: none; 
}

.menu ul li:last-child
{
 border-bottom: none;

}

.menu li:first-child a:hover{
 border-radius: 10px;
  background:#fff;
}

.menu li:last-child a:hover{
 border-radius: 10px;
  background:#fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Link 1 </a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 2 </a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 3 </a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 4 </a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 5 </a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

> Blockquote

Answer (score 1):

Try this, You have to target your `li` element instead of `a` tag.

```css
.menu ul
{
 background: #ede0b3;
 width: 200px;
 box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px grey;
 border-radius: 10px; 
 margin-left: 5px;
} 

.menu ul li
{
 list-style: none;
 border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
}

.menu ul li a
{
 padding: 10px 15px;
 display: block;
 color: black;
 font-weight: bold;
 text-decoration: none; 
}

.menu ul li:last-child
{
 border-bottom: none;

}

.menu li:first-child a:hover{
 border-radius: 10px;
  background:#fff;
}

.menu li:last-child a:hover{
 border-radius: 10px;
  background:#fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Link 1 </a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 2 </a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 3 </a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 4 </a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 5 </a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are facing is because you have border-radius property to li a:first-child , since each li tag have single a element that's why it affects your whole a element.

 **CSS**

```
 .menu li:first-child:hover a
 {
    border-radius:10px;
 }
```

Hope this will resolve your problem.. https://jsfiddle.net/xdn80b9f/1/

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```css
.menu ul {
  background: #ede0b3;
  width: 200px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px grey;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  padding-left: 0;
}
.menu ul li {
  list-style: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
}
.menu ul li a {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  display: block;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.menu ul li:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
}
.menu ul li a:hover {
  background: white;
}
.menu li:first-child:hover a {
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}

.menu li:last-child:hover a {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Link 1 </a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 2 </a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 3 </a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 4 </a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 5 </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

First I added `padding-left: 0;` to the `.menu ul` selector and then replaced your last style `.menu li a:first-child:hover` with following to only add top-left & top-right border for the first menu item and bottom-left & bottom-right border for last item:

```
.menu li:first-child:hover a {
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}

.menu li:last-child:hover a {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}
```